# Dockerize Java Cucumber

Tags: java, docker, cucumber, dockerfile, config

I would ask you for help with dockerizing java cucumber automation tool.

I created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM  java:8
VOLUME          /tmp
ENTRYPOINT      mvn clean test -Dtest=-Dcucumber.options=--plugin html:target/Destination --plugin json:target/CucumberJSON.json
```

I created this Docker compose file:

```
  # Docker compose file for cucumber

version: '3.3'

services:

  tool:
    image: "cucumber:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    build: .
```

I added into pom.xml docker properties, spotify-maven plugin as follows:

```
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <dockerImageName>cucumber</dockerImageName>
    </properties>

 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${dockerImageName}:${project.version}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <VERSION>${project.version}</VERSION>
                    </buildArgs>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>**/**</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I did `mvn clean install` and I received this error:

Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default) on project xxx: Exception caught: User config file C:\Users\lenovo.gitconfig invalid org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException: Cannot read file C:\Users\lenovo.gitconfig: Unexpected end of config file -> [Help 1]

My config file:

```
[user]
    name = xxx xxx
    email = xxx

[http "https://addressOfCompany"]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy =
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I changed pom.xml

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.4.13</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                            <imageName>${dockerImageName}:${project.version}</imageName>
                            <dockerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <VERSION>${project.version}</VERSION>
                            </buildArgs>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <include>**/**</include>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```